# Reorganizing Data Matrix

Tags: database, excel

I've got a 10 x 4000 data matrix ( A lot of blank values in there ) and right now they are organized where each row is an article and in each of those rows the article is read out with one word per cell.  I would like to organize it where each row is an article and each column is a unique term, where the value in the intersection is the number of times the word occurs in the article. (Can clarify more if necessary).  I've tried using pivot tables and other methods, but can't figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Somehow, the "excel" and "bigdata" tags just don't belong together.  40,000 cells is not "big data".

Comment: I would have liked to execute this in a manner that is appropriate for "big data", as I'm a beginner right now and this is one of the first data sets I'm working with! I do see where you are coming from though

Comment: Then perhaps use something other than excel. Consider R, and the `reshape2` or `tidyr` packages

Comment: Copy, Paste Special, Transpose.

Comment: None of these really answer what I am looking for.  I currently have the data sorted where each row is an article.  I would like it sorted where each row is an article and each column is a unique term.